# SQLCMD Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: sql, syntax, sqlcmd

When executing a stored procedure using SQLCMD with the following parameters:

```
. sqlcmd -S $sql_server -U $sql_usr -P $sql_pwd -d $sql_db -Q "EXEC $storedProc $dateVariable, $regionType, ALM.10.2.33.1" -V 1 -b
```

The following message is received:

Incorrect syntax near '.'.

If I pass ALM_10_2_33_1 instead of ALM.10.2.33.1, the stored procedure is executed perfectly.

Thanks,

Comment: did you try using `'ALM.10.2.33.1'`?

Comment: Dots are normally reserved in SQL for referencing objects... I'm assuming this is T-SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delimit the parameter correctly with single quotes

```
"EXEC $storedProc $dateVariable, $regionType, 'ALM.10.2.33.1'"
```

SQL Server has quirk that allows (var)char parameters to be specified without delimiters if they don't contain certain characters like `.`.

You can see it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx)

```
EXEC sp_addserver <'new_name\instancename'>, local
```

But if you check [sp_addserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174411.aspx), `@local` is `varchar(10)`, and `'LOCAL'` is mentioned as the value required.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping ALM.10.2.33.1 in square brackets:

```
[ALM.10.2.33.1]
```